# Need a Javascript searchable/filtrable combobox with remote json datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, combobox, validation

I need a combobox (Open source preferred) with this functionality:

1. Remote DataSource json format
2. Filtrable/Searchable
3. Data Value/Display Value
4. Integrated with ASP.NET MVC client side validation (no ExtJs)

I'm searching and testing from many days but I not found anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [jQuery UI autocomplete combobox example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

It uses an underlying html `<select>` element, so I assume it should work with your client side validation.

The example uses a pre-defined list of options, but you can modify it to use an AJAX call instead.  See their other autocomplete examples.